# How to generate and save multi barcodes into folder by php?

Tags: php, text-files, directory, jpeg, barcode

I have tried to generate many barcodes by barcode generator. There are many codes I have put in text.txt. But It is fail after I run below codes. Is there any mistakes? Please help.

Here is text.txt

```
ABC0000001
ABC0000002
ABC0000003
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');

require_once('class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');

//I run the barcode text one by one here
foreach(file('text.txt') as $line) {
    $font = new BCGFontFile('./font/Arial.ttf', 18);
    $color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
    $color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

    $text = $line;

    $code = new BCGcode128();
    $code->setScale(1);
    $code->setThickness(30);
    $code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
    $code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
    $code->setFont($font);
    $code->parse("'".$text."'"); // Text

    $drawing = new BCGDrawing('images/filename'.$text.'.jpg', $color_white);
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw();

    $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_JPEG);
}
?>
```

Below is the error section

```
$c = count($posArray);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            if (($curLen[$posArray[$i]] + $charSiz[$posArray[$i]]) < $nxtLen[$posArray[$i]]) {
                $nxtLen[$posArray[$i]] = $curLen[$posArray[$i]] + $charSiz[$posArray[$i]];
                $nxtSeq[$posArray[$i]] = $curSeq[$posArray[$i]] . '.';
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
                if ($j === $posArray[$i]) { continue; }
                if (($curLen[$j] + $shftLen[$j][$posArray[$i]] + $charSiz[$posArray[$i]]) < $nxtLen[$j]) {
                    $nxtLen[$j] = $curLen[$j] + $shftLen[$j][$posArray[$i]] + $charSiz[$posArray[$i]];
                    $nxtSeq[$j] = $curSeq[$j] . chr($posArray[$i] + 65) . '.';
                }
            }
        }

        if ($c === 0) {
            // We found an unsuported character
            throw new BCGParseException('code128', 'Character ' .  $input . ' not supported.');
        }
```

Comment: are there any errors being displayed?

Comment: it show"Fatal error: in /home/content/93/10958793/html/barcode/class/BCGcode128.barcode.php on line 708" @DevDonkey

Comment: can we see that section of code? (update your question)

Comment: Updated the error. I saw it just said not support, but I can add one barcode of my text files. What's going on? @DevDonkey